# Google I/O Android Sample Application

Tags: android, user-interface, io

I heard recently that Google were to opensource the Google I/O Android application - the one which showed the next available talk, speaker info, etc. Does anyone know whether this is true, and if it is, do you know where I can access the source?

On a related note, does anyone know of a sample application which concentrates on some of the Android UI best practices. Some of them are described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html, but it'd be great to see some sample application which displays some of the best practices described in the UI talk at Google I/O this year (like the Twitter sample application they showcased)

Cheers

Sean

Comment: I'd also be interested in this. For reference, this is the talk in question: http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)'s the src.

About the `Android` ui patterns:
There have been some questions on stackoverflow and we are all waiting for the twitter app src code. It will be released as open-source sooner or later.

Comment: Cheers Macarse - FWIW, I heard recently that the Twitter guys are scrubbing the application in anticipation of opensourcing it. Lets hope its sooner rather than later because there's a lot of functionality in that application I think we could all benefit from seeing how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [demo project](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/) that shows how to implement QuickActions and the Popdown menu featured in the I/O talk and the Twitter app.